# I can't import the Tor gpg debian repository keys

Tags: tor-install, debian, raspberry-pi

I am on raspbian on a raspberry Pi model 2.
I can't import the keys for the Tor repository. I tried the two following commands:

```
$ gpg2 --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

And:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
gpg: packet(13) too large
gpg: read_block: read error: Invalid packet
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I followed these instructions: https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

I have no idea what is going on here. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Grab the latest build of Tor project from their download page for linux. I just did it and was 8.5.1.

Make sure you are in the same directory you downloaded the Tor project in to. In my case I downloaded it to `~/Downloads`

`cd ~/Downloads`

Add the keyserver

`gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290`

Add the fingerprint

`gpg --fingerprint 0x4E2C6E8793298290`

Download the .asc key from the small link directly under the Tor bundle download button labeled as [sig] for signature. When you click on the [sig] button it opens up the key signature URL, For future reference one can just swap out that link for the one we will `wget` below. The file name should be the exact same name as the Tor version you downloaded but with an added `.asc` extension.

`wget https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/8.5.1/tor-browser-linux64-8.5.1_en-US.tar.xz.asc`

Then you can check the file against the .asc file

`gpg --verify tor-browser-linux64-8.5.1_en-US.tar.xz{.asc,}`

These steps were taken directly from the How can I verify Tor Browser signature. Follow the link below if you would like to see sample output from the commands and further description. I added the above wget command to easily grab the signature and name it accordingly.

`https://support.torproject.org/tbb/how-to-verify-signature/`

Also as a side note, I have noticed that adding a key from the keyserver might fail if you are using a vpn. I had to disable mine.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much luck with getting this key using gpg2. Try:

```
# wget https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc
# apt-key add <A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc
```